# Filter Contacts by Email Domain

Tags: wordpress, contacts

I'm trying to filter my contacts so I can easily identify a subset of those from the same organisation in order to fill in the relationships side of the CRM. I have a custom report to view all contacts, but there's no filter option for the e-mail heading of data.

Would this need to be done as a separate report perhaps?

e.g: E-mail is equal to "@shsc.nhs.uk"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done via the search function, doing a search for the e-mail domain will yield all contact results matching that domain, which you can then bulk select and from the Actions menu add a relationship to an organisation.

Comment: Cool. You should also be able to set up a rule, using CiviRules, to automate the same process for new e-mails added.